# Simplify indices expression

Tags: index-notation

Neither I nor my maths teacher can simplify this expression to get the answer in our textbook. Can you show us how, or is the textbook wrong?

[The expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taGoG.png)

The textbook claims the simplified expression is:$$4/21$$

Answer (score 1):

It is simply a matter of rearranging the numerator and denominator:

Observe that your equation is the same as:

$$\frac{7^{2x+1}-7^{2x-1}-7^2+1}{36 \cdot 7^{2x} - 36 \cdot 7}$$

After rearranging numerator and factorizing denominator this simplifies to:

$$\frac{(7^{2x+1}-7^{2})-(7^{2x-1}-1)}{36 \cdot 7(7^{2x-1} - 1)}$$

More factorizing on numerator

$$\frac{7^2(7^{2x-1}-1)-(7^{2x-1}-1)}{36 \cdot 7(7^{2x-1} - 1)}$$

Now it's just $$\frac{49-1}{252}=\frac{4}{21}$$

It would seem your textbook is right.